# Create an controller in app folder in cake php?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to create an controller in app folder in cake php?

```
class AppSessionController extends AppController {

}
```

I want to create another controller parallely to AppController, then I want to extends it with AppController

The new created controller can be extended to whole application(All controllers in app/controllers).

Is it possible ?

EDIT: 
In app/controllers

```
class customController extends AppSessionController {

}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You want to create an AppSessionController and then have all your controllers extend AppSessionController?

Comment: @tigrang: Yes, Needs a controller which can be extended like AppController to whole application .The new created controller want to extended from AppController also

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you don't implement it just in AppController but if you really have a need you can do 1 of two things

A)

```
class AppController extends CustomController {}
CustomController extends Controller {}
```

B)

```
class CustomController extends AppController {}
Update all controllers to extend CustomController
```

Or if its just common functionally, perhaps a Component will do then add the component to AppController

Comment: Is it possible to not load all component files in component array in app_controller for a controller with particular method

Comment: In which destination can I create custom_controller.php `app folder` or inside `app\controller`...